# errno 0 with swiftmailer

Tags: php, sockets, ipv6, swiftmailer, digital-ocean

Digital Ocean blocks `smtp` in IPv6 (and the request times out since the server fetches gmail in IPv6 first) so in order to still send mail using swiftmailer configured with gmail I tried two different techniques to force IPv4:

```
$smtp_host_ip = gethostbyname( 'smtp.gmail.com' );
$mailer->getTransport()->setHost( $smtp_host_ip );
```

and

```
$mailer->getTransport()->setSourceIp( '0.0.0.0' );
```

And I get the following error in both cases:

```
Error message
----------------
Connection could not be established with host 74.125.136.108 [ #0] 
File
--------------
/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
```

I checked the PHP documentation of [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php):

> If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE,
>   it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call.
>   This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket.

I had connection timeout error in IPv6 So I suppose there is no problem initializing the socket. But the error is not very talkative.